# How can I check whether or not a file is an image?

Tags: php, image

Can I check whether or not a certain file is an image? How can do this in PHP?

If the file is not an image, I want to give an alert message.

Comment: many similar questions already asked on SO...Please try searching

Comment: @MitchWheat: i search but i cant find properly how to check and implement.

Comment: do u browse and import a file or read it directly from a particular source?

Comment: @sree: yes and when click on the submit button  i want to check.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), you can use [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

> exif_imagetype() reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature.
>
> When a correct signature is found, the appropriate constant value will be returned otherwise the return value is FALSE. The return value is the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but exif_imagetype() is much faster.

For both functions, FALSE is returned if the file is not determined to be an image.

Comment: -1 - Both of these functions throw read errors, at least in 5.3.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Please clarify.

Comment: For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363876/handle-error-when-getimagesize-cant-find-file) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175758/getimagesize-read-error).   In my case I was getting for `'.'`, `'..'` and `'.DS_Store'` which it's reasonable for me to filter out. But you can't catch the Read error so you have to make sure it can never occur by checking everything that might cause a problem _(file exists, correct permissions, other?)_ in advance.

Comment: Well yeah you should use `is_file()` first @MikeSchinkel, this is not a replacement for that.

Answer (score 2):

in PHP you can do it like following way

```
if ((($_FILES['profile_picture']['type'] == 'image/gif') || ($_FILES['profile_picture']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') || ($_FILES['profile_picture']['type'] == 'image/png')))
```

in Javascript You can do it like following way

```
function checkFile() {
   var filename = document.getElementById("upload_file").value;
   var ext = getExt(filename);
 //  alert(filename.files[0].filesize);
  // alert(ext);
   if(ext == "gif" || ext == "jpg" || ext=="png")
      return true;
   alert("Please upload .gif, .jpg and .png files only.");
   document.getElementById("upload_file").value='';
   return false;
}

function getExt(filename) {
   var dot_pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
   if(dot_pos == -1)
      return "";
   return filename.substr(dot_pos+1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: I am sure that he needs to check if whether the file isn't just renamed sheet.pdf to sheet.jpg. You get what I mean.

Comment: dnt say sorry, you made a good point of renaming sheet.pdf to sheet.jpg, i will have to work on that part, thanks for idea

Answer (score 1):

In  `php` we can use `filetype ( string $filename )`   and `mime_content_type ( string $filename )`

but `mime_content_type ( string $filename )` is `deprecated`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php

In `javascript` we can use custom functions

http://my-sliit.blogspot.in/2009/04/how-to-check-upload-file-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to find out...

```
$type =array('jpg','gif');

foreach($type as $val){

if($_FILES['filename']['type'] == 'image/$val')
{
echo "its an image file";
}
else{
echo "invalid image file"
}
```

Comment: I have not downvoted.. Rarely I down vote one answer.. If I have any doubt about your answer, I will ask you, not downvote.

Comment: its for who ever has downvoted.. but, appriciate ur thought though ,i do the same...

Answer (score 0):

Better and faster way is to use [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). Something like that should do the work:

```
$valid_formats = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
$file_format = exif_imagetype($filename);

if(!in_array($file_format, $valid_formats))
    echo("File format is not valid");
```