# Phpunit: how to assert that a file is an image?

Tags: php, image, unit-testing, phpunit

Is there a way to check if a specific file is an image using phpunit?

Comment: Is this you are searching for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969211/phpunit-image-download-test ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'mime_content_type' function to obtain file's MIME type. Then, for example, you can assert that the returned value is equal to 'image/png' or starts with 'image'.

Comment: that worked, thanks!